# Use a user library that uses external jars

Tags: android, eclipse

Suppose we have a user library project ProjectUserlib that uses an external jar external.jar, and a project ProjectFoo that uses ProjectUserlib.

It seems that ProjectFoo has to add external.jar to its libraries if it uses a class of ProjectUserlib that requires external.jar. In other words, not only does external.jar have to be added to ProjectUserlib, but also to every project that uses a class in ProjectUserlib requiring external.jar.

Could anyone confirm this, or offer a tip about how to avoid adding external.jar to any projects that use ProjectUserlib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is stated in the official dev guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

> **A library project can include a JAR library**
>
> You can develop a library project that itself includes a JAR library, however you need to manually edit the dependent application project's build path and add a path to the JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm this.

I have a Main Project, which references a Library Project . The external JAR is included in my Library Project, but when I run the Main project it complains that the JAR is missing.

I had to add the JAR to the build path of the Main Project in order to correct the issue, even though it was present in the libs folder of the Library project, and the Library Project was included on the build path of the Main Project.

If anyone has found a better way I would love to know.